# Проблема получения значений из файла на html + flask

Tags: html, python, form, flask

Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы значения из списка Python добавлялись в форму ввода без использования библиотек JS? Мне нужно добавлять их отделяя запятой между собой. Проблема в том, что я могу выбрать одно значение с помощью тега `datalist` и не могу сделать это второй раз, хотя цикл у меня есть, но что-то работает не так. Вот код:

`app.py:`

```
import csv
from flask import Flask, jsonify, make_response, render_template, request,

with open('templates/Testing.csv') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        values = next(reader)
        values = values[:len(values)-1]

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def page_show():
    return render_template('includes/default.html', values=values)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

`default.html:`

```
    <input type="text" id="values" list="val" multiple="multiple" class="searchTerm" name="value" placeholder="Type your values">
    <datalist list="values" name="values">
    {% for val in values %}
      <option value="{{val}}" SELECTED>{{val}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </datalist>
    <button type="submit" class="searchButton" name=form>
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </button>
```

Подскажите в чем ошибка и как можно решить?